# Linq SQL datetime invocation error on app close

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I'm having some difficulty figuring out how to fix this. It runs perfectly fine but throws an TargetInvocationException error on

```
var person = (from c in DB.Persons 
                          where c.ID == Convert.ToInt32(cmbID.Text)
                          select c).First();
```

when closing the application. The error is with a DateTime field called dob, but I'm unsure how to grab that correctly.

```
private void cmbID_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Fill out the other boxes in relation to the person ID selected.
        var person = (from c in DB.Persons 
                      where c.ID == Convert.ToInt32(cmbID.Text)
                      select c).First();
        txtFName.Text = person.FName.ToString();
        txtLName.Text = person.LName;
        dateTimePicker1.Text = person.DOB.ToShortDateString();
        txtPhone.Text = person.Phone;
        txtAdd1.Text = person.Add1;
        txtAdd2.Text = person.Add2;
        txtSuburb.Text = person.Suburb;
        cmbState.Text = person.State;
        txtPostcode.Text = person.Postcode;
        cmbType.Text = person.Type;
    }
```

I am very new to Linq and SQL, sorry if the error is blatently obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following where the event is removed so it will not be triggered.

using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.FormClosing += formClosing;
        }

        private void formClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged -= comboBox1SelectedIndexChanged;
        }

        private void comboBox1SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // your code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Karen! Looking very promising but I do currently have an error on `this.FormClosing += formClosing;`.
"No overload for 'formClosing' matched delegate 'System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler'."

Comment: Ahhah! I entered FormClosedEventArgs, rather than FormClosingEventArgs. :) Thanks again!